# Multiple json in one foreach

Tags: php, json, foreach

Hey i have five json from all getting information now i encountered with problem like this -> from five different json i need to get **latest** **videoId** who newer shows first and all it need put to one function foreach for my too hard i try it do about 5hours and stay in same step

[Json 1](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=UCKLObxxmmAN4bBXdRtdqEJA&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyDVTF2abNVa5pRitb8MVz1ceJFhE-2y_qk) [json 2](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=UCynfZM0Edr9cA4pDymb2rEA&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyDVTF2abNVa5pRitb8MVz1ceJFhE-2y_qk)

All code need from this two json get latest(newest) **videoId** in one foreach echo

```
<?php
$videoList1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=UCKLObxxmmAN4bBXdRtdqEJA&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyDVTF2abNVa5pRitb8MVz1ceJFhE-2y_qk'));
$videoList2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=UCynfZM0Edr9cA4pDymb2rEA&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyDVTF2abNVa5pRitb8MVz1ceJFhE-2y_qk'));

$i = 0;
foreach($videoList1->items as $item){
    if(isset($item->id->videoId)) {  
        echo $item->id->videoId;
        if ( ++$i > 3) {
           break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Your post is hard to understand, can you formulate again exactly what you need? Also, why is your code not using `$videoList2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tray this:

```
$videoList1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=UCKLObxxmmAN4bBXdRtdqEJA&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyDVTF2abNVa5pRitb8MVz1ceJFhE-2y_qk'),true);
$videoList2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=UCynfZM0Edr9cA4pDymb2rEA&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSyDVTF2abNVa5pRitb8MVz1ceJFhE-2y_qk'),true);

$videoList = array_merge($videoList1["items"],$videoList2["items"]);

/// sort lastet first
  foreach ($videoList as $key => $part) {
     $sort[$key] = strtotime($part['snippet']['publishedAt']);
  }
  array_multisort($sort, SORT_DESC, $videoList);

 foreach ($videoList as $video) {
    if(isset($video["id"]["videoId"])) {
      echo 'publishedAt: '. $video['snippet']['publishedAt'] . ' VideoID:  ' .  $video["id"]["videoId"] . "\n </br>";
    } 
 }
```

Comment: And for the "newer shows first" part, [`usort`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) on `$videoList[$i]['snippet']['publishedAt']`.

Comment: First json have 50videoid second 9videoid a see 59videoid as result

Comment: Yes sorry i was watching published date but there just combine thanks now need do latest videoId show first :)

Comment: yes it's works perfect now ! thanks you are great now i know how do multiple jsons  thanks !

Comment: Just a side note... calling the count() within the for statement is not as efficient as storing the count() to a variable and using that. So `$videoListCount = count($videoList)-1;` and `for( $i= 0 ; $i <= $videoListCount; $i++ )`. Just keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: Is it better now?